# Classic ASP: parent.parent.getelementbyID from iframe in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have inherited an old classic ASP website, where part of the interface is done in nested iframes. In the nested iframe, the value of a text-field in the parent of the parent is set, but this only works in Internet Explorer

A simple snippet:

```
function Test() {
parent.parent.document.getElementById("myField").value = "Test"; 
} 
...  
<input id="myField" type="button" onclick="Test();"/>
```

How to I get this to work in Chrome? Or Edge for that matter..

Comment: This is entirely client-side code. ASP is irrelevant to it, There is no obvious reason why that would fail to work in browsers other than IE. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Check if sandbox attribute is present on the iframe elements, IE<10 didn't support sandbox attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
parent.parent.document.getElementById("myField").value = "Test";
```

To

```
parent.parent.document.forms["formName"]["myField"].value = "Test";
```

seemed to do the job. There are multiple forms in the parent.parent page, and eventhough the ID and names are unique, specifying the form seems necessary.

Comment: I bet you only have the name for the input, that explains why `gEBI` would work in IE only.